# ERROR in Compute Engine VM Instances

Tags: cloud, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

Does anybody knows something about this error?
Today, I couldn't see my virtual machines in Google Cloud (Compute Engine > VM Instances), and this message showed up:

> An unknown error has occurred in Compute Engine: "Service internal
>   error occurred.". Error code: "internalError"

Answer (score 0):

This may not be of value to you, but I experienced the same error in Chrome during my initial setup. It appears that the correct order of creating a VM instance is NOT by going through Compute Engine -> VM Instances, but rather counterintuitively (at least for me) through Compute Engine -> Images and then checking the box next to the OS of your choice. That allows you to select "Create Instance" above. Once you created your instance, the option of VM instances will become available. Did that help?

Comment: Thanks Frank! I'll take your advice when creating a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Google support and was told there was a general issue on April 8 that caused this error. They said it was resolved on the same day at 23:35 UTC.

Comment: Yup. All back to normal. :) Thanks.